# Autoscrolleable TableView

Tags: qt, tableview

I think this is an easy one, but I can't solve it by myself.
I'm using a `TableView` from QML, and from Qt with a timer I'm sending info to the `TableView` to generate new rows.
I want the `TableView` autoscroll itself and always showme the last row I add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an answer

```
TableView.positionViewAtRow( TableView.rowCount -1, ListView.End)
```

I used folibis/Benjamin answer but I have to do it with a TableView, I found this answer to my problem, hope it helps some one else

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
ListView.positionViewAtEnd();
```

to scroll to the end of list or use

```js
ListView.positionViewAtIndex(int index, PositionMode mode)
```

to scroll to specified index.
Pay attention, you must call this functions only after the list was loaded (generally in `Component.onCompleted`)